# Unable to share url with string in whatsapp

Tags: ios, text, ios8, share, whatsapp

I'm trying to share text + url thru WhatsApp, but not getting anything populated in the WhatsApp textfield.

I have tried following code :

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mouthshut.com/contest?ref=%@&inv_via=whatsapp&act=reg", UserName];

//NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
//urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString * urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=Writing a review is better than whatsapp. Win cash prizes daily on MouthShut.com \n Join Now %@", urlString];

NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlWhats stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
} else {
  UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert!" message:@"Your device has no WhatsApp installed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
}
```

Comment: May I know why this question have been down voted?

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mouthshut.com/contest?ref=%@&inv_via=whatsapp&act=reg", UserName];    
        urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"%3A"];
        urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"%2F"];
        urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@"%3F"];
        urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"%2C"];
        urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D"];
        urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26"];

    //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    //urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString * urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=Writing a review is better than whatsapp. Win cash prizes daily on MouthShut.com \n Join Now %@", urlString];

    NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlWhats stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
    } else {
      UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert!" message:@"Your device has no WhatsApp installed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];
    }
```